# Updating pivot table fields using a referenced cell in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have set my rng to be an exact match to the PivotField ("Sum of Mar-20"), can anyone help me resolve as its not working. Thank you

```
Sub Test1_DimCheck()

Dim daterng As Range
Set daterng = Sheets("Navigation").Range("A1")

Sheets("Global Forecast").PivotTables("PivotTable10").PivotFields(daterng). _
    Orientation = xlHidden

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if this matters here but have you tried `daterng.Value`?

Comment: @urdearboy Thanks! That actually worked